# Shell Script: command line argument with quotes

Tags: shell

I have a script which takes command line arguments and after some processing, it sends these arguments to the java application.

Some of these arguments can be quoted and I want to send those arguments as it is (in the quote). I am using following script:

```
$ARGS=""
for a in $@; do
    ARGS = ${ARGS} ${a};
done
exec $JAR $ARGS
```

where **$JAR** contains command to run the jar.
But, if I run the script with following options:

```
script x y "a b"
```

The script treats the three parameters as *x*, *y* and *a b*.
And I want it to consider these parameters as: *x*, *y* and *"a b"*.

Comment: The user will provide the command line arguments. So, I need to do the processing in the script itself.

Comment: With the example arguments to the script, how should the `exec` line inside the script look like? `exec $JAR x y "a b"`?

Comment: yes. but it is preferable to have it as three arguments viz. x, y and "a b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use an array for the arguments.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
$ARGS=()
for a in "$@"; do
    ARGS+=("${a}")
done
exec "$JAR" "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Comment: It will not work for me. I need to process some of the arguments differently (which are not shown in the example above). So, the loop is necessary in this case. Sorry! I was not clear initially.

Comment: Main answer still doesn't change.