# Passing command line argument from the terminal with apostrophe or quote

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have seen questions about passing arguments with quotes to a shell script (e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606818/shell-script-command-line-argument-with-quotes)).

My situation is slightly different:

I am passing an argument to my java program from the bash terminal. The number of possible arguments is finite (20, to be precise), and one of them is "alzheimer's". But if I type

```
java -cp ... myclass --term alzheimer's
```

this is what I see:
[image]

.. and then I have to ctrl+C out of it.

Everything works fine if it's a single word with all alphanumeric characters. What should I do for this one case with the apostrophe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote it; the single apostrophe, when it itself is not quoted, is treated as the beginning of a quoted string. `bash` is waiting for you to complete the quoted string.

```
java -cp ... myclass --term "alzheimer's"
```

or

```
java -cp ... myclass --term alzheimer\'s
```

Comment: Gah, thanks! I always escape single quotes (while grepping, for instance), but this time, my mind was calling it "apostrophe", and I never thought of it as a single quote! Now I have to wait for 7 minutes before I can accept this answer. Will this work with non-bash shells?